# Where to ask about the meaning of a joke?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If you have a short fictional story which you don't quite get, where on Stack Exchange would you go?

Comment: It is hard to say without an example of the question but https://literature.stackexchange.com/ or https://writing.stackexchange.com/ would be good places to start. Do read their help first though.

Comment: If it was in English, maybe https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jokes or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jokes. It can help to post the question you're planning to ask, or a summary of it.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you're learning English or if not, [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

English Language Learners has a [jokes](/questions/tagged/jokes) tag.

> This tag is for questions about interpreting jokes and understanding humorous wordplay.

While English Language and Usage has a [joke](/questions/tagged/joke) tag.

> Questions about humorous expressions, jokes, puns, etc.

Check out their help centres and other questions before posting so you know what they might expect. Given the differences in the tag descriptions it does sound like ELL is where you should be.