# Is there a Stack Exchange site for asking joke questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site for asking joke questions, or is that just not in the spirit of Stack Exchange?

Comment: What's a "joke question", exactly? Do you have an example?

Comment: Why is my negative Gravioli detector detecting positive Gravioli?

Comment: No. It's not in the spirit of Stack Exchange. We only discuss crime, death, bad code, hats... and unicorns. (Very, very, very seriously, of course.)

Comment: But if you want to create a new site for jokes, propose it on Area 51. (https://area51.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Additionally, every year, [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) has something called [Purim Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) where they ask often humorous/satirical questions. Note that this is only on-topic for a specific time, and that such questions are closed once the occasion passes

Comment: Note that it's possible to [ask **about**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355165/282094) interpreting a joke, if you don't understand English sufficiently well, but telling jokes is off-topic everywhere (unless you succeed in creating a new site), and humor should be very carefully incorporated into questions, answers and comments; as some people had their sense of humor shot off in the war.

Comment: Related on Area 51 DIscussion: [The Closing of Humor](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24036/106460)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was one such actual proposal in the past, as far as I can tell, it was called Apocalyptic Defense. The [proposal itself](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2868/apocalyptic-defense) was closed and deleted despite [people here appealing the decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53811/why-was-apocalyptic-defense-closed).

If you want to take a look, there's [web archive of it](https://web.archive.org/web/20100606214013/https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2868/apocalyptic-defense). In case it's taken down, here's also a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbCgh.jpg).

Bottom line: Stack Exchange is meant for professional sites, not jokes or humorous sites. No point suggesting such a site, as it would be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such site in the Stack Exchange network at the moment.

You could try suggesting such a site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), but be aware it takes quite a bit of time and energy to actually make a new community happen.

Comment: Reddit is far easier for this sort of thing: just set up your own r/whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Questions on Stack Exchange have definitive answers. Sites that accept subjective questions have ways of vetting answers that prevent it from being a free for all. That's why your example joke question wouldn't fly anywhere.

Still, some sites have what may be considered "joke questions".

- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/): Questions are puzzles, some of which are written in character. The [puzzles can't be open ended](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/25084).
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/): Questions are code challenges, some of which are written in character, though they always have to find a way to mention what golfing rules are being used.
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/): Questions are about making a fictional world, sometimes written in character
- [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/): We accept some questions about writing jokes. For example [How to make innocent jokes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/31998/34330)

Comment: For all intents and purposes, "joke" questions are [off topic on Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1517/66833). Challenges do still include the odd bit of humour in their specifications, but so do a lot of questions across the network

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I edited to try to clarify. I'm talking about questions tagged code golf that are written in character ([quick example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111380)). I've also seen the rules written in character but they're always at least acknowledged.